# Two closely related projects -- Two repositories or one?

Tags: project-management, git, project-structure, forking

#### Background

I am coding two closely related Java projects.
The first project is Single Facility Simulator,
which simulates a very simple supply chain with a single facility.
The second project is Supply Chain Simulator,
which simulates more complex supply chain networks,
i.e. multiple facilities arranged as a graph
with directed edges between some pairs of facilities.

The first project is a "toy" project in the sense that
I am using it to test and refine the high-level design of the project.
The second project is the "real" project that I am interested in for work purposes.
The high-level design of the two projects is the same,
although there are some differences,
for example a `Demand` object in the "toy" project only needs to generate a demand value per time period,
whereas a `Demand` object in the "real" project needs to generate a demand value per facility per time period.

#### Question

Currently, the "toy" project lives in its own Git repository.
As I begin implementing the "real" project,
should I fork the "toy" project,
or should I implement the "real" project as different packages in the same space as the "toy" project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO this decision should depend on the intended life cycle of your projects. If you are going to develop your "toy" project further, in parallel to your "real" project, and if you want to create a combined release of your both projects whenever you create a release of your "real" project, then one repository is better. But if you want to decouple the life cycle of your real project (almost) completely from your toy project, then two separate repositories will most probably be the better alternative.